# How to load a third party class on deployee of war file into tomcat

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, jms

Requirement:

I have two modules:

1) JMSClient (jar)
2) webapplication (war)

This two programs are working fine as individuals.

Now my requirement is, On deploy of webappication into TomcatServer, The MyListnear class in JMSClient jar should get called and  JMSClient should be up and running.

To meet this requirement, I have deployed JMSClient.jar under `WEB-INF\lib`
updated the web.xml file with

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>com.jmsapiclient.JMSListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I'm not sure how-far this is correct. Can some body help me with the better approach .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not package the JMSClient.jar into war file?

Comment: Thanks for response, Ideally I want to use JMSClient for different projects, If I have JMSClient program in war will that work, I mean my JMSClient is listning to Jboss-ESB, when I deploy war into tomcat , is it passible to recive the messages automatically ?

Comment: I have package the JMSClient into war, Now I'm getting bellow Stack trace 
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name ConnectionFactory is not bound in this Context
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:770)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
 at

Answer (score 0):

If your JMSListener implements the `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener` interface then it will be notified with the `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0)` message if the context has been initialized.

If you are implementing a web application using the Servlet 3.0 specification you can annotate your class with @WebListener (`javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener`). So it is not necessary (but still possible) to declare it in the web.xml file.

This implicates that they are deployed in the same context.

Comment: I have did  the same, Now I'm getting "Name ConnectionFactory is not bound in this Context" error, when I deploye my application